# How to use protobuf payload with UDP protocol in Netty? Could you give me a example for this with custom protobuf protocol?

Tags: java, netty, rpc

How to use protobuf payload with UDP protocol in Netty? Could you give me a example for this with custom protobuf protocol?
And there is only one example about it with TCP protocol.

public void bind(int port) throws Exception {

```
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class).option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 100)
                .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO)).childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(new ProtobufVarint32FrameDecoder());
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(new ProtobufDecoder(RichManProto.RichMan.getDefaultInstance()));
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(new ProtoBufServerHandler());
                    }
                });


        ChannelFuture f = b.bind(port).sync();

        System.out.println("init start");

        f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } finally {
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try some code first.

Comment: As i known Netty need us to use NioDatagramChannel when UDP using. i want to use protobuf  but i got NioDatagramPacket . Then how to convert it to protobuf ?

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same problem. But I am going to refactor the code to receive a DatagramPacket which convert into byte[], and then use parseFrom(byte[]) method to deserialize back to ProtoBuf object.